# InternetAddress Parse failing on Mime Headers because of certain emails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-api, mime

The `InternetAddress.parse(String addressList, boolean strict)` function part of the `java-gmail-imap`is used to parse email lists separated by `,` of the form `host@domain` and `Personal Name <host@domain>` that conform to the RFC822 standard.

This is typically used to parse the mime headers of an email (This is present in the `MessagePartHeader` in the `Message` object returned by the gmail api).

**Question**: The `parse` method throws an `AddressException` when it encounters an email address it cannot parse. The problem with this is that it is unable to parse the entire address list because of potentially one faulty/malformed/non-ascii email address. Is there a good way of splitting the mime headers (such as to, bcc, cc) into individual email addresses and parsing them individually? (This is not as simple as a split on `,` because names can potentially contain `,`). This way I can localize the bad email address.

In addition, are there better java mime parsers that can parse emails that contain non-ascii characters in email addresses (RFC6530, RFC6531 and RFC6532)? This way I can have a better chance of parsing this localized faulty email address that doesn't conform to RFC822.

Comment: Are you calling the InternetAddress.parse method explicitly?  Or are you depending on the implicit parsing done by the MimeMessage class?  If the latter, set the [`mail.mime.address.strict`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.address.strict) Session property to `false`, which should ensure that you never get an AddressException.

Comment: I am calling the `InternetAddress.parse` method explicitly. What should I do for the former scenario?

Comment: Call the [parseHeader](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parseHeader-java.lang.String-boolean-) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of JavaMail 1.6.0 has introduced a new session property, that allows for UTF-8 mail addresses. Just set `mail.mime.allowutf8` to `true` in your Session properties.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.mime.allowutf8", true);
Session.getInstance(props)
```

see the [changelog](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/JavaMail-1.6-changes.txt)